# select2 rails form sends nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, tags, jquery-select2, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm stacked. I'm using select2 and acts_as_taggable to tag my order model. Here is a code

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :tag_list, "TAGS" %><br>
<%= f.select :tag_list, options_for_select([['Human', 'Hs'], ['Mouse', 'Mm'], ['Yeast', 'Sc']]),{},:multiple => true, :class =>"category" %>
</div>
```

And also script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {$(".category").select2(); });
</script>
```

All works fine without connecting script ( with select2) but if with, it looks like working good but it sends empty strings and after submitting you didn't get any tags here.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you put your controller code and the log showing which parameters are passed to your controller when you submit your form?

Comment: @DiegoSenott http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31994057/using-select2-gem-with-acts-as-taggable-gem-on-rails check this one