# using select2 gem with acts_as_taggable gem on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

Im using select2-rails gem in my rails app. I found a problem here:[image]

Problem in tag_list. As u see it starts with ["",...] what wrong. Because of this my tag_list became empty after submitting. Without select2 it works fine. Can any one help?

My erb code

```
<%= f.label :tag_list, "TAGS" %><br>
<%= f.select :tag_list, options_for_select([['Asst', 'As'], ['Mouse', 'Mm'], ['Yeast', 'Sc']]),{},:multiple => true, :class =>"category" %>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [select2 rails form sends nothing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31990026/select2-rails-form-sends-nothing)

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here: 1) the tag_list parameter is not permitted in your controller and 2)Select2 is returning an array to your controller. To solve this, in your controller permitted params, you should declare the tag_list param like this:

```
tag_lists: []
```

It must be in PLURAL.

You should take a look at [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) regarding strong parameters.

Comment: U are right, it works if form returns string of sybmols like tag_list=>"1","2". Tag list is permitted.  How should i change returnable value from array to string?

Comment: You can convert it after you receive it, doing this:

    tag_list.join(',')